# Python shell unresponsive in emacs

Tags: python, shell, emacs

I'm trying to use emacs as my python develloping environement. But I'm facing a problem.
All communication between emacs and any python interactive shell that is called by python-shell seems broken:

The shell seems to start normally, displaying versions and giving me a prompt but then as I enter commands, nothing seems to happen. I have no answer from the interpreter. I can keep writing things but they then stay there in the middle of the screen and nothing happens. I've tried setting regular python interpreter to python and ipython and nothing changes.

I also try to invoke a system shell, that works correctly, and then call python or ipython from there, that brings me back to the same "no response" situation. It just looks like a normal buffer that I can edit. I can delete through the prompt, write some character anywhere in the screen, in the version info... It doesn't looks interactive at all.

What could be the reason of this problem?

Comment: Does this happen also when starting from emacs -Q?

Comment: emacs -Q doesn't change the problem

Comment: Hmm, what's your Emacs version? Maybe display the python-related output of M-x describe-mode RET for help?

Comment: Describe-mode indicates me that I am in Inferior Python Mode , the upper part of the buffer says I am using Python 2.7.5+ but actually it fails also on a more recent version that I have installed elsewhere (2.7.7) or when I try to use IPython. It seems to be a communication protocol problem between Emacs and Python interpreters. Emacs version is 24.3.1

Comment: IIUC you see the Python version displayed by banner text. That means a python-process is connected to buffer - good news. Remains the question which way that process is cancelled. Which command started the python-shell and which commands/keys afterwards?

Comment: The problem occurs indiferently from whichever command leads to a python inferior shell. In my case I tried elpy-shell-switch-to-shell from the python mode elpy, and also python-shell-switch-to-shell both of them calling the various interpreters I have installed on my machine (python and ipython). I still get this strange buffer where I can enter commands without second prompt, edit wherever I want, and of course I don't get any return from the interpreter.

Comment: We can only discuss this here from emacs -Q and also only one instance at once.  So  M-x python-shell-switch-to-shell RET - what are there precise commands/keys afterwards?

Comment: After launching python-shell-switch-to-shell it asks me which interpreter I want to use (I can choose whichever I want, Ipython or regular python, with or without the -i option), then I'm asked if I want to start a dedicated process for it. In every combination I end up with the same problem. I can see the different interpreters loading in, with different version info headers, but they all turn to be somehow unconnected buffers.

Comment: I just wiped out emacs from my system and intalled a fresh 24 version, and starting it with no configuration file, the problem with the python inferior shell is still here